# AWS: Delete Permanently S3 objects less than 30 days using 'Lifecycle Rule'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, bucket

Is there a way to configure on S3 Lifecycle to delete object less than 30 days (say I want to delete in 5 days Permanently  without moving to any other Storage class like glacier? 
Or should I go by other alternative like Lambda ?

I believe, S3 'Lifecycle Rule' allows storage class only more than 30 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [expiration action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html):

> Define when objects expire. Amazon S3 **deletes expired objects** on your behalf.

You can set expiration time to 5 days or 1 day, or what suits you.  For example, for a version bucket you can delete both current and previous versions after 5 days as shown on the screenshot:

[image]

Regarding the storage classes. You can still delete the objects, but you will be charged for 30, 90 or 180 days, [depending on the storage class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html), if not deleting from the Standard class:

> If you create an S3 Lifecycle expiration rule that causes objects that have been in S3 Intelligent-Tiering, S3 Standard-IA, or S3 One Zone-IA storage for less than 30 days to expire, **you are charged for 30 days**. If you create a Lifecycle expiration rule that causes objects that have been in S3 Glacier storage for less than 90 days to expire, **you are charged for 90 days**. If you create a Lifecycle expiration rule that causes objects that have been in S3 Glacier Deep Archive storage for less than 180 days to expire, **you are charged for 180 days**.

Comment: Marcin, Thanks a lot for your explanation. If I dont add any 'transition' setup for any version and directly setup 'expiration' and then deletion, then I won't be charged right? I mean, Standard S3 and direct deletion only after 5 days, then I am accountable only for S3 5 day stogae charges only right?

Comment: @Krishna Yes that's correct. If you are in standard class (default one) than you can delete at any time without paying for 30 or more days.

Comment: @Krishna No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: Good explanation. Is there any way we can configure object deletion rule for specific directory in the bucket?