# Amazon S3 aws: Deleting folders older than 5 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to delete folders older than 5 days that are in a folder in a bucket. I tried with the aws console by setting a rule that deletes the old folders of the "xyz" folder: I used the prefix "xyz /". Does not work! Can someone help me?

Thankyou!
Antonio

Comment: Do they really call them folders? Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS: Delete Permanently S3 objects less than 30 days using 'Lifecycle Rule'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62143832/aws-delete-permanently-s3-objects-less-than-30-days-using-lifecycle-rule)

Comment: Please note that folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. They can be 'created' simply by putting objects in a given path, and will disappear when all objects are removed from that path. If a folder is created in the S3 management console, then S3 actually creates a zero-length object with the name of the folder to 'force' the folder to appear.

Comment: I have to delete sub-folders older than "x" days. These folders/objects are contained in a folder inside the bucket. I set up a rule specifying the folder name as a prefix (which contains the sub-folders/objects to be deleted) but it doesn't work.